Error in accessing to pdb table as other user
When I connect to my pluggable database and create a table as DBA the table is works fine and 'EXISTS' but when I connect to my pdb as another user the table doesn't exist despite the fact the user and table is part of the same tablespace
enter image description here
enter image description here
I gave the necessary privileges to the account(CONNECT, CREATE SESSION, SELECT) but it seems non effective, the listener is also works well.

And what gives "select * from fcdirector.workcell ;" ?

Thank you, the  "select * from fcdirector.workcell ;" statement returns the table and it's content.
